# CodeIgniter - Refresh div after submit form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

My controller get datas from database model, and sends them to view. In view i do foreach loop to draw divs to each entity. Every single div has a form element to rate its entity.

Controller:

```php
function index(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'list';
    $data['entities'] = $this->database_model->getEntities();
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}

function postRate(){
    $rate = array(
        'entity_id' => $this->input->post('entity_id'),
        'owner_id' => $this->input->post('owner_id'),
        'value' => $this->input->post('value')
    );
    $this->database_model->persistRate($rate);
    $this->index();
}
```

Model:

```php
function getEntities(){
    return $this->db->get('entity')->result();
}

function persistRate($rate){
    return $this->db->insert('rate', $rate);
}
```

View:

```php
<?php foreach($entities as $entity) : ?>
    <div class="entity">
        <?php echo form_open('entities/postRate/', $attr); ?>
        <?php echo form_hidden('entity_id', $entity->id); ?>
        <?php echo form_hidden('owner_id', $userid); ?>
        <?php echo form_hidden('value', 1); ?>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', '+1'); ?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this case after rating, entire page will be reloaded but i want to refresh only that div where form was submited. I know javascript or jQuery can do it, ..
UPDATE
.. but i don't know their logics, how will they know the exact div or the exact (updated) data of actual entity ? Shall i get it from database? i'm just confused with js/jquery/ajax.

Comment: Look into AJAX. It doesn't matter whether you are using CodeIgniter or not, it really has nothing to do with that.

Comment: here the logic is the next, after submit on view, controller calls model and after it returns, call index method where get datas again and load the page again. right? i see it, but what is the logic with ajax? i don't see or i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple and can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/your_site/controller/method/",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : 123},
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
  }
});

<div class="result">
//YOUR AJAX RESULT WILL BE HERE
</div>
```

Your controller method should receive a post variable called `id`.

That is a basic example, you really should read the link and learn more about it. ;)

Comment: Okay, now i can send POST to http://localhost/my_site/controller/method and it just work, but how can PHP send response to $.ajax ? return entity; in the end of the method doesn't work. in success: function(data) { alert(data) } is absolutely empty.

Comment: i changed return entity; to print_r(entity); and it seems to work. Could it possible ?

Comment: no, it was stupidity, my last question is still active, how can PHP method send back any response to $.ajax ? Please help

Comment: with `echo`, so if you want, for instance to return a table, you should do this: `echo "<table><tr>Line</tr><td>Column</td></table>"`. This is what `JS` will receive in return and you place it where you need, following my answer.